# JBOSS 7.1.1 server hangs during the compilation of jasper reports

Tags: java, jboss, jasper-reports, client, server

My developer server is JBOSS AS 7.1.1 final and I have an app where I make dynamically an jasper report based on some arguments with these basic operations(download, compile, export to pdf, encode to base64, display on screen).

The thing is that on my JBOSS it works perfectly, but when I deploy the WAR file to the client server, it just halts/hangs/stops in the middle of compilation with no errors. I checked the log, but it just stops randomly and says nothing.

Comment: `it just halts/hangs in the middle of compilation with no errors` - Did you try to dump thread?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, what actually happens is that there were some errors and they weren't shown in the log when I tested with the WAR file. But when I tested with the WAR folder from my developer JBOSS it showed the errors.

Answer (score 0):

First of all check client jdk it mast me < 1.8

Comment: the jdk is 1.7 on my server and on the client too.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe some libs are in compile mode and didn't present on client server?